# My g++ executable doesn't run

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, gcc

I was refreshing myself with C++ today, and I wrote a hello world .cpp program using notepad++, then compiled it using g++.  The executable, when called from the windows command prompt, doesn't run, but is still open by the command prompt and I don't know why this is happening.  I also tried using gcc to compile a C program and it worked fine.  I installed both gcc and g++ using MinGW on Windows 8.  I've checked the path variables, I've reinstalled g++ using MinGW, and I've restarted the computer all to no avail.  The code is shown below.  Thanks for all your help!

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

  std::cout<<"Hello World";

  return 0;

}
```

The command I used to compile the .exe is:

```
g++ -o my_output_name my_input_file.cpp
```

When "my_output_name" is typed into the command prompt, the little blinky cursor jumps a line, like it's going to write out "Hello World!" but never does and just hangs up there.

Comment: Is it your source file name  `my_input_file.pp` or `my_input_file.cpp`?

Comment: You're right, That was just a typo on the stack exchange posting.  Thanks, I  edited it.

Comment: what happens if you change it to `std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;` ?

Comment: I tried that too, `std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl; ` was the first thing I tried.  It worked as well as the above example.  It didn't work at all.

Comment: I've also tried `using namespace std;` too so don't ask, haha.

Comment: Flushing shouldn't make a difference, the standard streams flush when they're destroyed at the end of the program. Stupid question but are you absolutely sure you are running the executable you just compiled, and not something from an earlier test?

Comment: That might be it, because there's this other application that says it's open in the command prompt but I have no idea how to close it.  I don't know what process to close in the task manager.  Also since it's open I can't delete it.  I just checked and it shouldn't be running, but when I tried to delete it it said it was open by another program.  Do you have any idea how to delete it or close it?  It's called "cpp_review.exe".

Comment: I've tried "CTRL + C" And that didn't work.  I've been able to open new instances of the command prompt without problems.

Comment: @Cate Try this: `g++ my_input_file.cpp` followed by `a.exe`.

Comment: @user657267 It just hangs up again.  When I press "Enter" to execute "a.exe" the cursor jumps a line and just sits there and blinks

Comment: @Cate Stupid question number 2: are you sure the content of `my_input_file.cpp` is exactly the same as what you've posted above?

Comment: @user657267  Yes, I cut and pasted that information.

Comment: @Cate: Do you use Avast antivirus?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I do use Avast.  Why would that make a difference?

Comment: @Cate: I guess something recently changed in Avast's heuristics or virus signatures triggering all these false positives. If you don't mind, I'll flag it as a duplicate. You can upvote the answer over there if you insist. Glad to help.